# how to connect mysql database in python using pymysql,KEY ERROR

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

im pretty new with python,im sorry if my question and my english doesnt sound right at all.
ive been trying to integrated my scraping output to mysql,but unfortunately i got stuck.can you good people help me?

### *the output/error*
*<pymysql.cursors.Cursor object at 0x000000E81FF095E0>
<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x000000E81FEF9070>

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
9     data = csv.DictReader(scrapeddata)
10     for row in data:
---> 11         sql = "INSERT INTO emas ( tanggal, terakhir, pembukaan, tertinggi, terendah, vol, perubahan%) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(str(row["tanggal"]),str(row["terakhir"]),str(row["pembukaan"]),str(row["tertinggi"]),str(row["terendah"]),str(row["vol"]),str(row["perubahan%"]))
12         print(sql)
13         cur.execute(sql)

KeyError: 'tanggal'*

this is my code

```
import csv
import pymysql
#Connecting to MySQL in Windows
conn = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port = 3306, user = "root", passwd = '', database = "mysql", 
charset = "utf8")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE historis")
print(cur)
print(conn)

with open(r'C:\Users\shulhan\output_emas.csv') as scrapeddata:
data = csv.DictReader(scrapeddata)
for row in data:
sql = "INSERT INTO emas ( tanggal, terakhir, pembukaan, tertinggi, terendah, vol, perubahan%) 
VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"
    %(str(row["tanggal"]),str(row["terakhir"]),str(row["pembukaan"]),str(row["tertinggi"]),str(row["terendah"]),str(row["vol"]),str(row["perubahan%"]))
    print(sql)
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your connection setup should look like this:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='user',
                         password='passwd',
                         db='db',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

you can find more information here:
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html